# Ionic + Firebase - Real time database not updating view

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have a really weird problem with my application. In order for the real time database to display, I have to interact with the application. 2 months ago I did not have this problem, the information appeared normally, but now, I have to click on a button or something in order for the view to update.

I made a quick GIF here:

If you pause just as I click the `<- back` button you'll see what I mean.. https://i.gyazo.com/44b450aa502dc7f37e5a5feea19824c6.mp4

I don't know what I did to make this happen..

Here is a code example from my application:

`.ts`:

```
  if(fromClick) { this.subscription.off(); }
  this.postFeed = new Array();
  this.subscription = this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.locationId)
  .orderByChild('score')
  .limitToLast(10);
  this.subscription.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
  });
```

`.html`:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let post of postFeed.reverse(); let i = index">
    <post [postData]="post"></post>
  </ng-container>
```

So this code above used to work perfectly, but now I have to interact with my app for it to display on the screen, even though the `postFeed` console logs perfectly fine. **The data shows up in the console exactly when I request it, but it doesn't show on screen.**

Any ideas? As I said, it used to work fine. Any help would be great! Thank you

Comment: my code snippet also broke recently and I did not update any code or local dependencies. So it seems worth checking if firebase did any breaking changes recently..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has this problem, `NgZone` was the answer for me.

I imported it:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

added it to the constructor:

```
public zone: NgZone,
```

and then wrapped it around my firebase code:

```
  this.zone = new NgZone({});
  if(fromClick) { this.subscription.off(); }
  this.postFeed = new Array();
  this.subscription = this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.locationId)
  .orderByChild('score')
  .limitToLast(10);
  this.subscription.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
     }):
  });
```

and this worked wonderfully for me. I couldn't find the actual *cause* of the issue, but I just wrapped the `NgZone` code around all my firebase functions and it worked like it used to. If anyone else has more information that would be great.

Comment: Did it start to happen after you begin using WKWebView